# Format Conversion from COCO JSON to VGG Image Annotator

Tags: python, json

I am working with https://github.com/mdhmz1/Auto-Annotate repo. In this repo, https://github.com/mdhmz1/Auto-Annotate/blob/main/customTrain.py file needs VIA JSON annotations file. I have my own annotations file in COCO JSON format. How can I convert my COCO JSON file to VIA JSON file?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I tried to look for a solution at [link] (https://roboflow.com/formats) but there I was not able to see a conversion where I can go from COCO JSON to VIA JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think you can try to use Roboflow for that.

You can just upload your dataset there, and then export it in your needed format!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).